# I am trying to extract data from Google map Using VBA, Unfortunately facing some error

Tags: vba

Please help me someone to solve my error, as I am new to coding and programming. I am trying to fetch some data from google map. but facing some error here is my code

```
        Sub GextUrl()

        Dim MSX As Object
        Dim HTML As HTMLDocument
        Dim Key
        Dim Url As String
        Dim lr As Long

        Set MSX = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        Set HTML = New HTMLDocument
        Set Key = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        

        
        Url = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Charu+Gupta+%26+Associates/data=!4m7!3m6!1s0x390cfa9c2e2fd7d5:0xa5817c778e83bd43!8m2!3d28.6666135!4d77.3773354!16s%2Fg%2F11g6xj9d6p!19sChIJ1dcvLpz6DDkRQ72Djnd8gaU?authuser=0&hl=en&rclk=1"
        
        With MSX
            .Open "GET", Url, False
            .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
            .send
            UrlResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
        End With
        
        HTML.body.innerHTML = UrlResponse
        lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        
        With HTML                
            Range("B" & lr) = .querySelectorAll(".DUwDvf")(0).innerText
        End With
    End Sub
```

I am facing error for querySelector that class is not available in UrlResponse, but when I check in chrome and Inspect there. this class is avaiable.

now I don't know how to solve these and get my result.

here is [URL Link](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Charu+Gupta+%26+Associates/@28.6666135,77.3773354,17z/data=!4m6!3m5!1s0x390cfa9c2e2fd7d5:0xa5817c778e83bd43!8m2!3d28.6666135!4d77.3773354!16s%2Fg%2F11g6xj9d6p?authuser=0&hl=en)

Comment: Unfortunately I get "Access Denied" when I try to run your code - however, instead of checking in Chrome you should check in Excel using the Watch Window to see if that class is available in the MSX.responseBody. You may be using a version of the object that doesn't recognise the class